# Laravel Socialite Sign in with google method

Tags: php, laravel, wifi

I am developer for `wifi` sign in with Google using Laravel application , 
in this application we are using Laravel Socialite , 
we have same coding wrote here :

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-google-oauth-authentication-using-socialite-packageexample.html

our customer can't login using mobile or phone , but everything working smoothly on desktop browser like chrome

we always get this warning message on phones   [image]

I also need to mention that on wifi connection its auto pop up mobile phone web-view landing page ,

Comment: Please email your client ID to "oauth-help@google.com". This seems like a known problem, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829530/google-oauth-2-0-and-captive-portal-with-embedded-browser#comment-81283657

Comment: I messaged google support but no reply untill now

Comment: Have you been able to solve it by now? If so, can you let us know how you did it? I'm running into this problem myself.

Comment: @AlmostPitt , yes , you will have to contact with "oauth-help@google.com". same solution mentioned by bitsapien above , its the correct solution and they will help you