# 'disallowed_useragent' error on captive portal

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, captiveportal

We are currently dealing with a big issue where our Captive Portal solution cannot work with Google OAuth and it is giving 'disallowed_useragent' error on iOS captive portal (seems to work on Android captive portal).

Our reference:
[Laravel Socialite Sign in with google method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708092/laravel-socialite-sign-in-with-google-method)

Other similar reference:
[Google OAuth 2.0 and Captive portal with Embedded browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829530/google-oauth-2-0-and-captive-portal-with-embedded-browser)

This is our oAuth 2.0 client ID - 474659916888-evuuf5df06snepug8cq18gpijpogn9tp.apps.googleusercontent.com
image.png

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, contact google oauth team and ask to be whitelisted

more info on :

[Google OAuth 2.0 and Captive portal with Embedded browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829530/google-oauth-2-0-and-captive-portal-with-embedded-browser)