# Disallowed User Agent (Google Oauth) in Captival portal

Tags: wifi, google-oauth, captiveportal

I am having one wifi captive portal Which asks user for "google plus" login first to continue wifi access. As devices do open embedded browser for this, Google OAuth 2.0 throws **403** error. **Error: disallowed_useragent**

Is there any way i can check that browsers is embedded or not with useragent string or something? So that in webpage i can put javascript code which will identify browser and eliminate google login option for that devices.

Answer (score 1):

i'm in the same situation, as reported :

[Google OAuth 2.0 and Captive portal with Embedded browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829530/google-oauth-2-0-and-captive-portal-with-embedded-browser)

.. we have to drop a message to Nvnagr (Google Team), with client-id and wait until he decide to "whitelist-us"

Hope to be next in whitelist  :)